# bash file without extension adding extension

Tags: file, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a very simple bash script in order to add a file extension (.java) to a bunch of files that have no extension.

If they had an extensions (say .txt) I'd do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `*.txt`; 
do mv $file $file.java; 
done
```

My files, however, don't have an extension. How do I make the loop? I tried `*.` with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
  mv "$file" "$file".java; 
done
```

If you only want to move files that do not already have an extension, try:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *; do
  test "${file%.*}" = "$file" && mv "$file" "$file".java;
done
```

Note that all of the double-quotes above are superfluous if your filenames are reasonable.

Comment: That renames all files including those that do already have an extension.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick :) I hope my question wasnt asked twice.

Comment: @Vicky Indeed it does, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: For bash 3 and higher you can do write it simplier with `mv ${file}{,.java}`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 | nawk '/.txt/{old=$0;gsub(/.txt/,".txt.java",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'
```

updated the answer from [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt ; do mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)txt/\1java/'` ; done
```

Comment: Same as `rename 's/.txt$/.java/' *.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/^\.\///; /\./d' | while read x; do mv "$x" "$x.java"; done
```